# why width 100% is not covered full screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have given body{width:100% ;height:auto;}
but it's not covered full screen its takes an extra and come scroller from left to right ...
full code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poTHP.jpg):https://github.com/Rabiulislamasa/PSD-to-WEB-TEMPLATE
Results:https://rabiulislamasa.github.io/PSD-to-WEB-TEMPLATE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row` has a `margin-right` and `margin-left` of `-15px`.

Comment: I need a small help, sir. I have converted a PSD to HTML. plz visit that and marked the wrong if have . link:https://rabiulislamasa.github.io/PSD-to-WEB-TEMPLATE/

Comment: @mdrabiulislamasa Sorry, I don't understand. What is it you're asking?  If you have a new question, you should start a new post.  Also, if I've answered your original question, please mark my answer correct.

Comment: sir that's problems come again in  small devices. i have use .row{margin-right:0% !important;margin-left:0% !important;} its perfect for dextop but the scroller comes again in the small device..what can I do now ??

Comment: @mdrabiulislamasa I'm not sure. When I checked, I'm not seeing a scrollbar.  I'd suggest inspecting the page to see if there are any css rules affecting smaller screen sizes. (i.e. media queries)

Answer (score 0):

that is because you have a margin computed in your  element (you can see this with the dev tools).